# referring page and javascript login issue

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, redirect

I have got a referring issue once again, this time using javascript.

The user click on myaccount.php page from index page but because they are not logged in they are shown the login screen. Once they are successfully logged in the user is taken back (redirected) to index page.

I am storing the referring URL using this code in javascript:

```
                    refering_url = document.referrer;
```

and then redirecting like this

```
                    window.location=refering_url;
```

This does not store the myaccount.php which redirected the user to login.php but instead stores index.php which the user clicked the myaccount.php link.

**Please note: The logging in is done using AJAX and AJAX call retruns "accept" once the users enters correct username and password. I am successfully receving the expected Ajax return value as "accept".**

Is there anyway to solve this issue.

Kind Regards

Comment: You need to use cookies to store data accross http request. A variable declared on a page will not be available on an other in javascript. everything is reset when the new page is loaded.

Comment: `refering_url` is = to index.php in this case

Comment: Are you using PHP or JS to redirect to the login page from myaccount.php?

Comment: @gillesc Cookies are just one of many ways to do this. PHP sessions, and query strings can also be used.

Comment: I am using JS to redirect after logging in.

Comment: I would suggest using PHP handle all redirections, that way you can append a query string with the referring page to the new URL you are redirecting to.

Comment: Please realize that you cannot rely on the "REFERER" HTTP property. It can be disabled, and it is not always relayed across insecure/secure connections. It's far, far better to use a mechanism completely under your control, like parameters explicitly included from page to page.

Answer (score 1):

Try using **HTTP_REFERER** in PHP to grab the URI and then redirect in PHP with `location()`

I hope that was helpful.

Comment: The problem is when I turn the JavaScript off everything would wok fine because referring works fine in PHP but how do I combine the PHP and JavaScript together?

Comment: You don't. Use php to handle everything

Comment: I have to implement the login screen using JavaScript.

Comment: all right explain why and how it works. is login process built in php ?

Comment: the logging is done using AJAX. the Ajax call returns accept and then JavaScript need to redirect to the referring page after receiving "accept" from Ajax request. Ajax call is successfully being received as "Accept"

Comment: well ok then pass the referrer uri using ajax : you can still use php to grab the uri...